# How to plot the standard error of linear combination of two variables in Stata

Tags: plot, stata, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot the 95% CI of a spline function in Stata. I can easily plot the fitted values, but am not sure how to calculate the SE here. Can someone please help?

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear

centile weight, centile(10 50 90)

calcspl weight, nknots(3) knotsat(r(c_1) r(c_2) r(c_3))
```

Or you could use another spline program, for example `mkspline` which will give you three covariates to include in the model, `weight1`, `weight2` and `weight3`

```
mkspline weight 3 = weight, pctile
```

This example is using the `calcspl` spline generation

```
regress mpg weight weight_1 foreign price

gen yfit = _b[weight]*weight + _b[weight_1]*weight_1

sort weight

twoway line yfit weight
```

Note that splines give you non integer values, so you can't use the margins command, and I have other covariates in my model, so I can't use the normal post estimation commands.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
set more off
sysuse auto, clear
mkspline weight 3 = weight, pctile
reg price weight?

/* Manual  Way That Will Also Work With Non-Integer Splined Variable */
predict yhat
predict se, stdp
gen lb = yhat - 1.96*se
gen ub = yhat + 1.96*se

tw (line yhat weight, sort lpatter(dash)) (rarea lb ub weight, sort fcolor(none))

/* Margins Way for Integer Splined Variable */
margins, over(weight)

/* Compare the Two In A Graph */
marginsplot, recast(line) recastci(rarea) addplot(line yhat weight, sort lpatter(dash) || rarea lb ub weight, sort fcolor(none))
```

`margins, over(weight)` gives you a predicted price at each value of weight and `marginsplot` gives you those predictions with the 95%CI in a plot. The `recast`s make the CI look nicer to my eyes.

---

Here's how I would get the **partial** effect. It uses the hack of setting all the other variables to zero before predicting and then restoring the data.

```
set more off
sysuse auto, clear
mkspline weight 3 = weight, pctile
gen constant = 1

reg price constant weight? i.foreign c.mpg, nocons

/* check one point using lincom */
list weight* if weight == 4840
lincom _b[weight1]*2640 + _b[weight2]*760 + _b[weight3]*1440

preserve
    replace constant = 0
    replace foreign = 0
    replace mpg = 0

    predict yhat
    predict se, stdp
    gen lb = yhat - invttail(`e(df_r)',0.025)*se
    gen ub = yhat + invttail(`e(df_r)',0.025)*se

    /* confirm that predict matches lincom's output for one point */
    list yhat lb ub if weight == 4840

    tw (line yhat weight, sort lpatter(dash)) (rarea lb ub weight, sort fcolor(none))
restore
```

I used the critical values based on the t distribution instead of the usual 1.96 that I used above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The `margins` command only works with integers though, and splines will give you non integer values.  Thus, I do not think this neat trick will not work for splines, unfortunately. I think I need to do this with the variance covariance matrix, but am not sure how to call/use this in `Stata`.

Comment: @Ashley I edited the code to deal with the non-integer issue. You should update the original question with that constraint.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Dimitriy. I edited my original post to specify that splines give you non integer values.  I thought about using the post estimation commands, but am adjusting my model for other covariates, so I actually want partial predictions for just my spline so I can then plot the graph for just the spline and the 95% CI.  So using `predict se, stdp` gives you predictions for the entire model, not just the spline.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll have to fix the remaining variables at some constant; predicting "just for the splines" means setting the remaining coefficients at 0, which may not be meaningful. You may get some inspiration here: http://maartenbuis.nl/wp/inter_quadr/inter_quadr.html